# Using the Python SQLite3 library on a server

Tags: python, database, sqlite, web

I have a program written in Python that reads from a .db file. I had an issue running this program on a web server using CGI scripts, and I eventually traced back the issue to importing the Python SQLite3 library, which was not even recognized. I should not the program runs just fine on my computer, just not on the sever.

I was just wondering whether there is another solution than to upload the entire Python library of built-in modules onto my server.

Comment: If you want to properly access the database, using a library made for the database seems like the only real option, right?

Comment: The problem is that my programming skills are limited to Python and Java, so learning something like MySQL for this task isn't ideal. If that's the only option, I guess I'll have to dive into learning that.

Comment: Where'd MySQL come from? I thought you had an SQLite3 database?

Comment: Well the database is generated using SQLite3 on my computer, but as I understand, accessing it can be done using other database libraries as well.

Comment: Only if you go to some effort to export the database in another format...

Comment: I see. Just one more thing, do you think dumping the entire Python lib directory onto my server would work?

Comment: No -- you may have different architecture or different paths for the support libraries. I suggest properly installing the libraries on the server...

Comment: sqlite3 has been included since Py2.5, your server must be running a very old version of python.